# JSON string in DOM does not match object in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, json

I am doing something similar to the following:

```
var car = {'make':'honda'};

console.log(car);

car.model = 'civic';

$('#car').text(JSON.stringify(car));

console.log(car);
```

When I open up developer console and type in `car`, I only see:

```
{make: "honda"}
```

If I do `console.log(car)`, I see:

```
{make: "honda", model: "civic"}
```

What could be the reason why I don't see my updated object when typing it in the Chrome console?

If I type in `JSON.parse($('#car').text())`, I see the whole object.  Is this how I have to do it?

Updated example:

The following happens in a jquery ajax success callback:

```
var localClientStorage = window.localStorage;

var car= localClientStorage.getItem("car");

car = JSON.parse(car);

car.model= 'civic';

localClientStorage.setItem("car", JSON.stringify(car));
```

When I type in car in the console, the model property is not there.

```
function getCarModel(make) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Car/GetModel',
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ make: make })

        success: function (data) {

                    var localClientStorage = window.localStorage;

                    var carObject = localClientStorage.getItem("car");

                    carObject = JSON.parse(carObject );

                    carObject.model = data.Car.Model;


                    localClientStorage.setItem("car", JSON.stringify(carObject));

             $('#carObject').text(JSON.stringify(carObject));

                    localClientStorage.removeItem("car");

            } 
    });
};
```

Comment: Can't replicate. Have you tried clicking the triangle icon before `Object` in the console to show more properties?

Comment: @joews - Yes, I can't seem to replicate it either when I do a similar approach in a jsFiddle.  Is it better to do JSON.parse($('#car').text())?

Comment: Please update the question with a [mcve]. Right now it's quite confusing because you have code referring to a `#car` element, but then later talk about a `#brontoJsonObject`. You can use a Stack Snippet (click on the icon that looks like a piece of paper with angle brackets on it) to do that within your question. Also, there are JSON strings and JavaScript objects. A JSON object is not a thing in JavaScript.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need to parse JSON from a text box?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - I have some JSON on a page.  When I do console.log(car) for example, I can see the model, but if I type it directly into the chrome console, I just see the make.  It is as if the updated object is not picked up by the chrome console.  It is kind of confusing to me.

Comment: What does `console.log(car)` have to do with the JSON on the page?

Comment: Something to be aware of: element IDs become global variables. So if you have an element with `id="car"`, then typing `car` in the console will show the element, not the variable you created with `var car = ...`

Comment: @Barmar - after updating car with something like `car.model = 'civic'`, console.log(car) shoes make and model, but typing `car` in the chrome console just shoes model

Comment: @xaisoft Neither of those is referencing the DOM.

Comment: @Barmar, so it is possible that I am seeing my original created object?

Comment: You shouldn't see either object. A DOM element is not a JSON object.

Comment: Maybe your variable isn't really the same as the ID?

Comment: The scenario you're talking about cannot be reproduced from the code you've shown. So there's something you're not showing us.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - I updated my post with what I am doing in a callback on an AJAX post.

Comment: "When I type in car in the console, the model property is not there." --- where do you set it?

Comment: @zerkms - Fixed, I had a typo.  I do it at `car.model = 'civic'`

Comment: It looks like you're making up code that is far from what you actually have. Not sure how it's possible to help you with that. With the provided code what you explained is barely possible.

Comment: @zerkms - That is the code... I just mentioned it happens in an ajax call in a success call back.  Not sure what else to say?

Comment: "I just mentioned it happens in an ajax call in a success call back." --- in the latest example there is no ajax calls, but localStorage. "Not sure what else to say" --- provide the **ACTUAL** code you're having problems with. Like exactly that very code without any modifications.

Comment: So you don't use the result of the ajax call?

Comment: If you review the [mcve] article I mentioned, you should know that we expect you to provide a way of reproducing the behavior you're seeing. So far, the two examples you've provided don't reproduce that. The first shows it work, the second throws an error because `localStorage.getItem("car")` returns `null` since it doesn't exist.

Comment: @zerkms - I added the full ajax call

Comment: Now show the exact unmodified output of `JSON.stringify(data.Car)`. I'm sure it does not have the `Model` property.

Comment: @zerkms - I just checked and it and it does have a `Model` property but it is blank.  Here it is:  `{"make":"honda","model":""}`.  One thing I noticed is that this is the original object when I first create it.  If I add anything to it such as `model`, `year`, etc,  it does not show the updated value.  I first create the object and store it in an `<script id="car"></script>`.  This fiddle works correct: https://jsfiddle.net/8jxqzuxc/1/, but not sure why mine doesn't update.

Comment: @zerkms - The response coming back from the ajax call does have a `Model property that is set to civic`

Comment: It does not, `Model` and `model` are different properties

Comment: @zerkms - I think you are confused. `Model` is a property that I get back in my response that has the value of `civic`.  I am setting a property (`model`) on my JSON object to the value of `Model`.  I am just trying to set one to the other.